# How to make IntelliJ use my local tomcat application server?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I have an application I need to run on my local tomcat server, but I can't find the option to use it anywhere. All the guides I find say I have to go to File | Settings, and under 'Application Server' add the tomcat with my parameters. However, Tomcat isn't in the list at all. When I click the plus sign, all I see available to me are Jetty, Weblogic, Google App Engine, Resin and JSR45 server. Did I miss a step to include Tomcat in this list or is there some other problem?

Edit: Using IntelliJ Ultimate version 10.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File->Settings, select "Plugins" and enable the "Tomcat integration" plugin.