# How do I get IntelliJ to use my tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get IntelliJ Ultimate 14.14 to run my mvn project on a tomcat 7 server. I have the Tomcat Integration Plugin enabled as recommended in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150105/how-to-make-intellij-use-my-local-tomcat-application-server) and I have tomcat installed. The issue I'm having is that when I go to `Run | Edit Configurations` and then try to add my server it doesn't show the Tomcat server as an option. The weird thing is it was working before, but I had to re-checkout the project, and now I can't get it to run.

How can I point IntelliJ to the install location of tomcat?

Edit: Since there seems to be some confusion, I've added a screenshot of my Edit Configurations window

[image]

As you can see, there is no option to select Tomcat in my Run Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Just add new tomcat local/remote configuration with using run configuration

[image: Just add new tomcat local/remote configuration with using run configuration]

Comment: This is what I was saying I couldn't do. It doesn't show tomcat server as an option.

Comment: Ok check the tomcat plugin, via using the confugure plugins wizard.

Comment: Alright, I tried that, tomcat wasn't showing up in the configure plugins wizard either.